# Qualitative Design of Experiments - 3 Factors 3 Levels - Categorical Response Variable

Tags: anova, chi-squared, multivariate-testing, experimental-design, minitab

I need to perform a design of experiments where I have 3 factors with 3 levels each (all numerical). But the end response is going to be - Good, Bad, Pass sort of deal.

I need to find the factors/interactions that have the most significant contributions. Could someone suggest how to go about doing this?

If there is a similar example worked out, please share the link.

Here are the input values:

```
Factor 1: 0.9, 1.0, 1.1
Factor 2: 0.4, 0.45, 0.5
Factor 3: 3000, 3600, 4200

Response: Great, Pass, Fail
```

Can this be done in ANOVA or should we use `Chi^2` or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Good question. There's a discussion on this topic on Researchgate [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_apply_a_Kruskal-Wallis_or_a_Friedman_test_for_2_or_more_between-within-subject_factors) where somebody asks a similar question to yours.